# How to git --unset-upstream on older versions of Git that don't have that option?

Tags: git, version-control

So we found ourselves in a situation where a remote branch was deleted prematurely and we still had outstanding commits we wanted to merge and recover. My initial thought was simply to do the following in the original developers working copy:

```
> git checkout local-branch
> git branch --unset-upstream
> git push -u origin remote-branch
```

However the developer in question found that this didn't work because the system he was running on had a particularly ancient version of Git installed and installing a newer version was not an option:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
error: unknown option `unset-upstream'
usage: git branch [options] [-r | -a] [--merged | --no-merged]
   or: git branch [options] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
   or: git branch [options] [-r] (-d | -D) <branchname>...
   or: git branch [options] (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
```

Fortunately for us the commits in question had been previously pushed to the remote repository so another developer with an up-to-date version of git was able to fetch and merge those commits into their own version of the local branch thus restoring the remote branch and allowing us to merge it:

```
> git fetch origin <sha1hash>
> git checkout local-branch
> git merge <sha1hash>
> git branch --unset-upstream
> git push -u origin remote-branch
```

However it seems like there should have been a way to unset the upstream branch in the original developers repository perhaps by editing configurations files thus allowing the original developer to restore the branch.

So how do I remove the upstream branch without using `git branch --unset-upstream`?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the branch `master` for example, run `git config --local -e` and remove the following lines:

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Or just run `git config --remove-section branch.master` if supported.

Comment: It's possible that there are more `branch.master.*` items, so it's safer to remove only the remote and merge settings.